# A rookies cry for guidance, ps written in java

Tags: java

I'm writing an Odd Even checker program and thought i'd finished it. When I went to run the program it only showed the print "Enter an integer:122" ! May someone please explain why it didn't give me the results I desire & help a rookie out with a fix :) ? Both the remainder and division symbol yield the same results in regards to my issue..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class OddorEven {

public static void main(String args[]) {

int num = 122;
System.out.println("Enter an integer:" +num);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
num = input.nextInt();

if ( num % 2 == 0 ) {
System.out.println("Entered integer is even");
} else {
System.out.println("Entered integer is odd");
}
}
}
```

Comment: did you enter a number?

Comment: Enter a number then press Enter key.

Comment: Try printing out the value of `num / 2` (e.g. `System.out.println(num / 2)- is it what you expected?

Comment: so, for you 4 is not even, since 4 /2 turns out to be 2? did you actually input an integer?

Comment: Jack, this code `num = input.nextInt();` is expecting you to enter your own number - did you do that?

Comment: From your question we can see that you are a rookie and the tag says it's in Java, so please reserve the title for information that describes the concrete programming problem you are facing.

Comment: No i haven't input a number, where would i input it ? doesnt num define the value of itself after assigning it a value of 122 ?

Comment: Pshemo I'm running it in cmd, and writing it in notepad++

Comment: Enter a number on the command line, else get rid of `num = input.nextInt();`  - this is blocking your program from advancing unless you enter some number

Comment: Andy Turner I'll give it a shot !

Comment: What do you mean command line ? I'll get rid of it and try running it

Comment: You wrote *I'm running it in cmd* - thats what I mean

Comment: Oh okay gotcha :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out ! I appreciate it very much, I hope you all have a wonderful morning/day/evening :)

Comment: TBH Jack, maybe you should delete this question as it is of very limited use to other people and it has not done your reputation any good.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want the user input the remove the line `num=input.nextInt()` 
and use `%` operator for checking even or odd.

otherwise

Use `%` (the remainder operator) instead of `/` (the division operator):

```
int num;
    System.out.print("Enter an integer : ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = input.nextInt();

    if ( num % 2 == 0 ) {
      System.out.println("Entered integer is even");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Entered integer is odd");
    }
```

output :

```
Enter an integer : 22
Entered integer is even
```

and

```
Enter an integer : 23
Entered integer is odd
```

Comment: @khalid even though this is indeed a grave error in his case, he would still get output.
the problem is the program expects input, and he doesn't provide any.

Comment: @KhalidShah yes, but you don't address the actual problem he has.

Comment: *Entered integer is odd* - hmm strange

Comment: @Stultuske what is the actual problem then ? he don,t want the user input ? what the result he desired ? his condition was logically wrong and i fixed it.. if he want to check the odd and even then he should use % operator istead of /.

Comment: still, you don't seem to understand the problem the OP has. yes, indeed, the wrong operator is a problem, but it's not what is blocking the OP. his line: num = input.nextInt(); is waiting for him to enter a numerical value in the console and press enter, while he thinks the hardcoded value: 122 is used as the input, and doesn't enter a new one. if the wrong operator was his problem, he would still get the "this is not even" message, which he is not getting

Comment: @Stultuske then simply remove the line `num = input.nextInt()`. whick blocks the input.

Comment: *remove the line num = input.nextInt(). whick blocks the input.* - yes maybe this is the correct answer,

Comment: a better way would be to explain him he needs to input a value. or do you think he should recompile this code each time he wants to run the test for a different value?